# Will the output of the HTML-to-Fable/Elmish tool also work for Giraffe's ViewEngine?

Tags: fable-f#, elmish, f#-giraffe

If I paste the output of an HTML-based design tool into Mangel Maxime's (or, Maxime Mangel's?) [HTML-to-Fable/Elmish Convertor](https://mangelmaxime.github.io/html-to-elmish/), will that output work if provided to [Giraffe's ViewEngine](http://Giraffe's%20ViewEngine) (i.e. HTML DSL)?

Superficially, both formats look very similar, and it would be great if this happened to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no it wont work the DSL are differents:
For exemple for this HTML page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-EN">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://an_url/file.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="elmish-app"></div>
    <script>var __INIT_STATE__ = "{\"SomeValueKey\":\"SomeValue\",\"AnotherValueKey\":\"AnotherValue\"}"</script><script src="http://localhost:8080/app.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/style.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/vendors~app.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/vendors~app~style.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `elmish` counterpart would be:

```ml
html [ Lang "en-EN" ] [ 
    head [] [ 
        meta [ CharSet "utf-8" ]
        link [ Rel "stylesheet"; Href "https://an_url/file.css" ]
        link [ Rel "shortcut icon"; Type "image/png"; Href "/favicon.png" ] ]
    body [] [ 
      div [ Id "elmish-app" ]
        [ ]
      script [ ] [ str "var __INIT_STATE__ = \"{\"SomeValueKey\":\"SomeValue\",\"AnotherValueKey\":\"AnotherValue\"}\"" ]
      script [ Src "http://localhost:8080/app.js" ] [ ]
      script [ Src "http://localhost:8080/style.js" ] [ ]
      script [ Src "http://localhost:8080/vendors~app.js" ] []
      script [ Src "http://localhost:8080/vendors~app~style.js"] [] 
    ] 
]
```

the `GiraffeViewEngine` counterpart would be:

```ml
html [ _lang lang] [
        head [] [
            meta [ _charset "utf-8"]
            meta [ _data "data-virtualpath" virtualPath ]
            link [ _rel "stylesheet"; _href (sprintf "%O" portfolioUrl) ]
            link [ _rel "shortcut icon"; _type "image/png"; _href "/favicon.png" ]
        ]
        body [] [
            div [_id "elmish-app"] []
            script [] [ rawText "var __INIT_STATE__ = \"{\"SomeValueKey\":\"SomeValue\",\"AnotherValueKey\":\"AnotherValue\"}\"" ]
            script [ _src (sprintf "%O%s" assetsBaseUrl "app.js") ] []
            script [ _src (sprintf "%O%s" assetsBaseUrl "style.js") ] []
            script [ _src (sprintf "%O%s" assetsBaseUrl "vendors~app.js") ] []
            script [ _src (sprintf "%O%s" assetsBaseUrl "vendors~app~style.js") ] []
        ]
    ]
```

Still it is very close, you should be able to adapt it very quickly by adding `_` to all attributes and convert them to lowercase.